# Google ML Kit face detector - detect incomplete face

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

I am trying to detect incomplete faces on ID documents using Google ML Kit but apparently ML Kit is auto-generating contours and landmarks for the face sections not visible. Please see the attached image below:

[image: Incomplete face detection]

How can I detect that the face is incomplete and display error to users accordingly. I am using following FaceDetectorOptions:

```
FaceDetectorOptions options =
                new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                        .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE)
                        .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                        .build();
```

Comment: What happens when you enable `FaceDetectorOptions.LANDMARK_MODE_ALL`?

Comment: No difference, MLKit detects all 10 landmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently ML Kit Face SDK is unable to detect whether face is covered or incomplete.

We will try to prioritize this functionality in 2022.

Comment: OK, looking forward to it.